# thread with temporary std::condition_variable gets stuck randomly in some situations

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++17, clang++, condition-variable

Recently I'm playing with `std::thread` and `std::condition_variable` but encountered something very confusing.

There are two threads in my plan, one to submit tasks and another to execute them. Also, there are two kinds of `std::condition_variable`. One is used to notify the task thread that a new task has been added. And another one is for notifying the main thread that a task has been executed (something like `std::promise` with `std::future`). Besides, a new task will be submitted only if the old one is done.

The expected code execution order is as follows:

```
main thread              task thread

     |    create thread       |
     | ---------------------> |
     |    push_back task 1    |
     | ---------------------> | 
     |                        |
     |    notify task 1 done  |
     | <--------------------- |
     |                        |
     |        ......          |
     |                        |
     |    push_back task 5    |
     | ---------------------> |
     |                        |
     |    notify task 5 done  |
     | <--------------------  |
     |                        |
     |    thread join         |
     | <--------------------- |
     |                        |
     v                        v
```

Code is here (**EDIT: code updated due to poor readability of last version**):

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

auto track(std::string const & message) -> void
{
    auto static mutex = std::mutex();
    std::scoped_lock _(mutex);
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
}

struct task_executor
{
public:
    task_executor()
        : rn(true)
        , ts()
        , mx()
        , cv()
        , th(&task_executor::execute, this)
    {}

    ~task_executor()
    {
        {
            auto ul = std::unique_lock(mx);
            rn = false;
        }
        cv.notify_all();
        th.join();
    }

    template<typename T> void push(T && func)
    {
        {
            std::scoped_lock _(mx);
            ts.push_back(std::forward<T>(func));
        }
        cv.notify_one();
    }

private:
    void execute()
    {
        auto todo = std::list<std::function<void()>>();
        do {
            todo.clear();
            {
                auto ul = std::unique_lock(mx);
                cv.wait(ul, [&] { return !ts.empty() || !rn; });
                std::swap(todo, ts);
            }
            for (auto& f : todo)
                f();
        } while (!todo.empty());
    }

private:
    bool                             rn;
    std::list<std::function<void()>> ts;
    std::mutex                       mx;
    std::condition_variable          cv;
    std::thread                      th;
};

auto main() -> int
{
    auto k = 1000;
    while (k --> 0)
    {
                                    track("CASE BEGIN " + std::to_string(k));
        auto te = task_executor();

        for (auto i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        {
            auto x = false;
            auto m = std::mutex();
            auto c = std::condition_variable();

                                    track("step " + std::to_string(i) + " (1/3)");
            te.push([&]
            {
                                    track("step inner (1/3)");
                {
                    std::scoped_lock _(m);
                    x = true;
                }
                                    track("step inner (2/3)");
                c.notify_one();
                                    track("step inner (3/3)");
            });

                                    track("step " + std::to_string(i) + " (2/3)");
            {
                auto l = std::unique_lock(m);
                c.wait(l, [&] { return x; });
            }
                                    track("step " + std::to_string(i) + " (3/3)");
        }
                                    track("CASE END " + std::to_string(k));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Notes:

- Function `track` is used to print execution order and could be ignored.
- Loop 1000 times because a single run does not always reproduce this problem.
- Compile with `-std=c++17 -pthread`.

But in some situations, the program may not be executed in that way and **get stuck**. I've tested it under three different OS and compilers:

1. MSVC v142 (Visual Studio 2019) \ Windows 10 20H2
2. GCC 10.2.0 \ Arch Linux (but forgot the version)
3. Clang 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4) \ Mac OS 10.14.6

It always works with MSVC v142 and GCC 10.2.0 but **randomly gets stuck if using Clang 10.0.1**. We may also reproduce it on an [online compiler](https://onlinegdb.com/Bye5Fz_Gu).

And here are my questions:

- Does my code meet my expectations and is there any bug in it?
- If the code is fine, then is it a problem with Clang or system libraries?
- If not, how could MSVC and GCC deal with this situation correctly?

---

EDIT: As the last version is not readable, I updated the code.

Comment: You are pushing functions into `ts` which refer to mutexes and conditional variables that are inside the `for` block? That does not look right.

Comment: I'm very confused by your code, even though there are a number of mutex and locks in there, you don't seem to use them properly. I think you should really think out your program again.

Comment: I'd group connected variables into structs, give them meaningful names, and write operations that aren't raw access to threading primitives and descibe what they do.  Then instead of having to hold the state of 10 variables in my head to prove the code is correct, I merely have to audit 3-4 at a time (does the function do what it says?  When I compose these operations, is that valid?).  Write a thread safe queue with push and pop; that replaces half of your variables with 1.  Write a gate (wrapping x).  There goes another 3 variables some manual locks.

Comment: Using threading primitives is hard.  You **need** to build abstractions that are as simple as possible and then sketch mathematical proofs of correctness.  If you do not, you will get deadlocks and race conditions.  Finding or fixing one particular deadlock or race condition does not make your code substantially more sound, and the effort to prove a flaw exists is 1000 larger than the effort to make your code provably correct to start; so writing code and finding a flaw afterwards is a waste of human thought.  This means structuring your code in a way that is easier to prove correct.

Comment: Fundamentally, I would be surprised if any code written like the above did not have threading errors.  It is possible you did the proof that it does not yourself, but then you wrote write only code, and found it doesn't work.  To solve your problem I would do what I suggested above, throwing out everything you wrote, and then maybe once I did have a correct solition confirm where your error is and/or that clang has a bug.  But probably you.  So please refactor!

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Thanks for your so many suggestions. I just added a more readable version at the end. And currently only tested on the online compiler and this problem still exists.

Comment: @JHBonarius sorry for the code. I wrote them together in order to reduce the number of lines but it seems to breaks readability. And a new version has been added.

Comment: @wilx I just add a more readable version. And the lifetime of `std::mutex` and `std::condition_variable` should be limited to the loop, so I think there should be no problem?

Answer (score 2):

Sure I can see potential UB.
This could lock up the threads.

Consider this particular ordering of calls.
Time goes down.

```
 Main Thread:                          Side Thread:
 Create Side Thread

                                       cv.wait()

 x = false;
 Push Functions "ts"
 cv.notify();


                                       swap(ts, todo)
                                       execute all functions in "todo"
                                           lock(m)
                                           x = true
                                           unlock(m)

 lock(m)
 c.wait() // does not wait as x is true
 unlock(m)
 // leaves scope
 // destructor called for
 //     x/m/c

 
                                           c.notify(); // Calling notify
                                                       // on destroyed object
                                                       // This is UB
```

Comment: Whoops, I thought there might be some extra operations after `c.notify_one()`. But the problem seems to be much more straightforward. Now I am curious why some compilers can handle it correctly.

Comment: as Yakk said "moves the notify into the mutex's lock"

Comment: @MYLS That statement makes no sense. I think you are misunderstanding what Yakk is saying. The compiler is handling things correctly. What you are doing is misunderstanding the constructs you need to build to get this correct.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct gate{
  void open(){
    auto l = std::unique_lock(m);
    is_open = true;
    cv.notify_all();
  }
  void wait()const{
    auto l = std::unique_lock(m);
    cv.wait(l, [&]{return is_open;});
  }
private:
   bool is_open = false;
   mutable std::mutex m;
   std::condition_variable cv;
};
```

then:

```
    for (auto i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
      gate g;

      track("step " + std::to_string(i) + " (1/3)");
      te.push([&]
      {
        track("step inner (1/2)");
        gate.open();
        track("step inner (2/2)");
      });

      track("step " + std::to_string(i) + " (2/3)");
      g.wait();
      track("step " + std::to_string(i) + " (3/3)");
```

as @martin noted, the problem looks like your condition variable c's lifetime is not properly guarded and is used after it dies.

This moves the notify into the mutex's lock; modern C++ compilers also make this optimal.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestions for improvement. The first version of my code is actually simplified from a more complex one. And that version looks very strange when debugging as it crashes randomly in many other places. Now I am very curious about the optimization and do you have relevant references about that?

Comment: @myls no but std libs expects the notify to happen in a mutex.  From my understanding, if you notify unlock, the waiting thread wakes once, not twice.  If you unlock notify, the waiting thread may wake twice.  But basically, signal within the cv's mutex.

Comment: I just found that my case has been listed in [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one). `Notifying while under the lock may nevertheless be necessary when precise scheduling of events is required, e.g. if the waiting thread would exit the program if the condition is satisfied, causing destruction of the notifying thread's condition_variable. A spurious wakeup after mutex unlock but before notify would result in notify called on a destroyed object.` Now it’s even more strange why it can run normally when compiled by some compilers.

Comment: @myls If you are surprised threaded code has hard to reproduce bugs you need to respect threaded code more.  Start doing proofs of correctness, at least sjetches, instead of pretending testing is sufficient.  (testing is also needed because people make errors in proofs)